# upcasting in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, casting

Hi I have a custom class that extends Sprite, that controls positioning on the stage.  I would like the class that manages the stage to be able to take any sprite that is added to the stage and convert it to custom class type, ie wrap it so that the managing class can position a native sprite accordingly.
Does anyone know if it is possible to do something like the following

```
var managed:managedSprite = new managedSprite(nativeSprite);
```

where the managedSprite extends the Sprite class? I don't want to have to composite in a reference to the sprite if at all possible in order to prevent the overhead associated with the managedSprite already extending Sprite.

Is there anyway using reflection (perhaps the commons.reflection library)?

Thanks

Comment: thanks, I've tried the upcasting approach by having a class extend MovieClip.  I've then tried classref = class(MovieClip) and I am getting a type coercion failed error.  I thought that upcasting like this was never a problem as the class extending movieclip always has a byte length of at least type movieclip length, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: It's valid AS3 if managedSprite takes a Sprite as constructor argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event listener to the stage and use `Event.ADDED` to get a reference to any display object added anywhere in the display list.

Then simply type cast if the added item is a subclass of `ManagedSprite` (BTW, the convention is to start your class names with an uppercase letter):

```
stage.addEventListener (Event.ADDED, onAdded); 

function onAdded( ev:Event ):void {
    if (ev.target is ManagedSprite) {
        var managed:ManagedSprite = ManagedSprite( ev.target );
        doStuffWith( managed );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I think I only just understood your question:  You are not trying to do an actual type cast - which would require your class hierarchy to be already set up, i.e. you'd have to have extended the ManagedSprite class already - but to add functionality at runtime!

I would strongly discourage you from trying to do deep copies or such - it will be heavy on performance, depending on how many sprites you are going to add, and you will no longer have your compiler to help you prevent errors.

Rather, see if you can't favor composition over inheritance: Create a kind of "proxy" class for the sprite, let's call it `ManagedSpriteProxy`, which implements all the methods you would call on ManagedSprite, but forwards all the actual manipulations to its `managedSprite' property.  Then use the event handler I outlined above to create the proxy objects and attach the respective sprites:

```
public class ManagedSpriteProxy {
    private var _managedSprite:Sprite;

    public function ManagedSpriteProxy( managedSprite:Sprite ) {
        this.managedSprite = managedSprite;
    }

    public function get managedSprite():Sprite {
        return _managedSprite;
    }

    public function set managedSprite( managedSprite : Sprite ):void {
        _managedSprite = managedSprite;
        setUpAnyHandlersOrWhatever();
    }

    private function setUpAnyHandlersOrWhatever():void {
        // Many wonderful things happening
    }

    // Many more wonderful things happening via public API
}

// somewhere else

public class SpriteManager {
    private var _managedSprites:Array = [];

    public function SpriteManager() {
        addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage );
    }

    private function onAddedToStage( ev:Event ):void {
        removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE );
        stage.addEventListener( Event.ADDED, onAdded );
    }

    private function onAdded( ev:Event ):void {
        if( ev.target is Sprite ) {
            addWithProxy( ev.target as Sprite );
        }
    }

    private function addWithProxy( sprite:Sprite ) : void {
        var proxy:ManagedSpriteProxy = new ManagedSpriteProxy( sprite );
        _managedSprites.push( proxy );
    }

    // Insert here whatever methods used to manage the sprites, 
    // all of them call the proxies instead of the sprites!
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this still means that if I have a sprite as event.target, I will not be able to cast it to ManagedSprite.  What I want to do is cast the sprite into the MangedSprite super class, essentially a deepcopy, but I cannot deepcopy all types of displayobjectcontainer - such as movieclip; as a matter of fact there don't seem to be any deepcopy methods or libraries available that might do this; the standard bytearray.read() trick doesn't work if casting it to a subclass of an object (although I've just realised that I might be able to do some byte manipulation plus casting so I'll try that.

Comment: thanks for your well illustrated answser.  I've tried the proxy class idea, compositing the superclass type in to the managed class is ok, but I want the managed class to extend the superclass so that I can perform succesful rtti and casts, and not have to implement all of the methods of the superclass in the proxy.

Comment: Well, then there's always the byte code manipulation way of creating proxies.  http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/proxy.html

Comment: I would probably not want to go down that road on a larger project, though.  Generating classes at runtime may have some advantages, but it is also very hard to maintain and keep clean, because it adds another abstraction layer by removing a lot of the actual implementation from the source code.  That may seem like it will save time now, but it can become very costly later, when you come back in a few months to make changes, or worse: someone else does.

Comment: actually, my bad, I think that what I am doing is not upcasting but downcasting.  I am afterall wanting to cast from movieclip to inherited_from_mc_class.  The dynamic proxy generation commons idea looks like good but is a lot of work in comparison to extending a movieclip for rtti and then compositing in a movieclip for use in a proxyclass, although it results in double the overhead.  I could sidestep the whole issue by simply making a proxy class which stores and returns the content as * but I prefer strongly typed code.  Thanks.

Comment: You've got me confused now.  If your Sprite extends ManagedSprite, all you need to do is add a type cast: `var spr:ManagedSprite = ManagedSprite( sprite );` and all methods will be available to you.  It doesn't matter if that's up or down casting. If your sprites are generic and do not extend ManagedSprite, then no type cast will work for you - you can only cast to a type that is in the object's class hierarchy.  If, furthermore, you want to add functionality that is not in the class hierarchy, then there is no way but to use dynamic (and thus weakly typed) code.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the 'Decorator' pattern.

It seems a little bit complex at the first sight but it's quite easy to understand and use.
http://www.as3dp.com/2009/04/actionscript-30-easy-and-practical-decorator-design-pattern/